# Import/Embed PDF Into HTML (For PDF)

Tags: html, python-2.7, pdf, wxpython

One of our applications creates an HTML report which is displayed to the user via their browser. This is subsequently converted into PDF file that can be e-mailed or viewed at a later time. The report can be classified as medical/lifestyle. I have been asked to allow the selection and embedding of various PDF(s), e.g. various diets and/or exercises into the HTML. The software is written in Python 2.7 and wxPython 2.8. I am trying to find a way to embed the PDF(s) into the HTML for viewing and then converting everything into the final PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I did some extensive research in this area a few months ago.  If you want to display a PDF using HTML I would first look at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

If your goal is to generate a PDF from an HTML page then I would recommend https://github.com/fraserxu/electron-pdf which is a server-side solution to generate and send a PDF back to the client.

With electron-pdf you have the option to run it behind a Node.JS API server which will keep an Electron instance running for the best latency.  Or, you can use the CLI to invoke exports from your Python code.

The Readme covers basic usage scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If running on Linux, check out `wkhtmltopdf`
The man page is as follows:

```
Name:
  wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.4

Synopsis:
  wkhtmltopdf [GLOBAL OPTION]... [OBJECT]... <output file>

Document objects:
  wkhtmltopdf is able to put several objects into the output file, an object is
  either a single webpage, a cover webpage or a table of content.  The objects
  are put into the output document in the order they are specified on the
  command line, options can be specified on a per object basis or in the global
  options area. Options from the Global Options section can only be placed in
  the global options area

  A page objects puts the content of a singe webpage into the output document.

  (page)? <input url/file name> [PAGE OPTION]...
  Options for the page object can be placed in the global options and the page
  options areas. The applicable options can be found in the Page Options and 
  Headers And Footer Options sections.

  A cover objects puts the content of a singe webpage into the output document,
  the page does not appear in the table of content, and does not have headers
  and footers.

  cover <input url/file name> [PAGE OPTION]...
  All options that can be specified for a page object can also be specified for
  a cover.

  A table of content object inserts a table of content into the output document.

  toc [TOC OPTION]...
  All options that can be specified for a page object can also be specified for
  a toc, further more the options from the TOC Options section can also be
  applied. The table of content is generated via XSLT which means that it can be
  styled to look however you want it to look. To get an aide of how to do this
  you can dump the default xslt document by supplying the
  --dump-default-toc-xsl, and the outline it works on by supplying
  --dump-outline, see the Outline Options section.

Description:
  Converts one or more HTML pages into a PDF document, *not* using wkhtmltopdf
  patched qt.

Global Options:
      --collate                       Collate when printing multiple copies
                                      (default)
      --no-collate                    Do not collate when printing multiple
                                      copies
      --copies <number>               Number of copies to print into the pdf
                                      file (default 1)
  -H, --extended-help                 Display more extensive help, detailing
                                      less common command switches
  -g, --grayscale                     PDF will be generated in grayscale
  -h, --help                          Display help
      --license                       Output license information and exit
  -l, --lowquality                    Generates lower quality pdf/ps. Useful to
                                      shrink the result document space
  -O, --orientation <orientation>     Set orientation to Landscape or Portrait
                                      (default Portrait)
  -s, --page-size <Size>              Set paper size to: A4, Letter, etc.
                                      (default A4)
  -q, --quiet                         Be less verbose
      --read-args-from-stdin          Read command line arguments from stdin
      --title <text>                  The title of the generated pdf file (The
                                      title of the first document is used if not
                                      specified)
  -V, --version                       Output version information and exit
```